# SELECT query from mysql with node js (LIKE query)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node js to develope my project, i use mysql to store my data.

I have a problem when i select with like query, and it give an error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test'%' ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 0,10' at line 1

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE fullname LIKE N'%'test'%' ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

I know error here is `'test'` in query, but it's a string, i can't remove it, my code here:

```
data = {};
data.fullname = 'test';
data.start    = 0;
data.limit    = 10;
let getFullname = function (data, callback) {
   return db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fullname LIKE N'%?%' ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT ?,? ", [data.fullname,data.start,data.limit], callback);
}
```

How can i solve my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, problem is mysql package add single quote `'`, you can use following manner

```
   return db.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE fullname LIKE N'%${data.fullname}%' ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT ?, ? `, [data.start,data.limit], callback);
```

or

```
data.fullname = '%' + data.fullname + '%';
return db.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE fullname LIKE N? ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT ?,? ", [data.fullname,data.start,data.limit], callback);
```

Comment: Yes, the second way work perfectly, because i must use prepare stament for secure my app

Comment: Can anyone explain what is the `N` in the `N?` part of the LIKE operation?

Comment: @Hiren `N?` means the string must start with the `N` character

Answer (score 2):

CONCAT("%", ? ,  "%")

:)

this is part of my code :

```
########## 

where += ` AND ( titre LIKE CONCAT("%", ? , "%") OR resume LIKE CONCAT("%", ? , "%") ) ` ; 
vals.push(dataRes.rech) ; 
vals.push(dataRes.rech) ; 

############# 

sql = `SELECT #########  WHERE 1=1 ${where}` ;  

connection.query( sql , vals , async function(err, services, fields) { 
if(err) rej({er : 1 , code : err , sql: sql , vals : vals}) ; 
else{ res({er : 0 , data : services }) }
```

Comment: Better to supply the complete context for your solution, at least the `return db.query()` part so it is perfectly clear where and how to insert this concatenation. Did you test this code?

Comment: this is part of the code : 

##########

  where += `  AND ( titre LIKE  CONCAT("%", ? ,  "%") OR resume LIKE CONCAT("%", ? ,  "%")  ) ` ;
        vals.push(dataRes.rech) ; 
        vals.push(dataRes.rech) ; 

#############

sql = `SELECT #########  WHERE 1=1 ${where} `

 connection.query( sql  , vals ,  async function(err, services, fields) {
       if(err) rej({er : 1 , code : err , sql: sql , vals : vals}) ;
       else{  res({er : 0 , data : services })  }